# Compare XML files on a Webpage

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to compare 2 XML files on a webpage. I was wondering if there is a tool that can be used to embed the XML compare viewer in a webpage. The user would select the 2 files to be compared and pass it to the viewer. The viewer should show compare results as shown in the XMLDiff/beyond compare tool. I would greatly appreciate any answer/suggestions.

Comment: I dont think this should be closed. Is there a `WebPage WinDiff` tool? I couldn't find one... maybe the answer is to use a Windows application with an API that your webpage uses, eg: http://wiki.winmerge.org/wiki/XML

Answer (score 0):

Try [Prettydiff](http://prettydiff.com/).  It is a XML language aware diff tool that works directly in your browser without sending your code anywhere.